# How do I get only the last value of a series in plsql?

Tags: sql

I have a base that captures the temperature every x time, for my current project, I would like to take only the value of the last temperature equal to the series, for example:

[image]

Comment: please tag your dbms

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by romaneio order by data desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```